# SQL Foreign Key based on column that specifies table

Tags: sql, mysql, database, database-design

Suppose I have a table that contains a list of ids pointing to table names, with the following schema:

```
RemoteTables
============
id (Primary Key)
tableName (string)
```

Suppose I also have the following schema in another table:

```
AnotherTable
============
id (Primary Key)
remoteTableId (foreign key referencing RemoteTables)
remoteId ("special" foreign key)
```

where `remoteId` points to a row in the table specified by `remoteTableId`.

I have seen a few situations where I wanted to do this, but is there any built-in SQL support to manage the relationship in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is a special type of constraint here, because you are building a custom meta-database (data dictionary of sorts).  So nothing "built in", per se.

Your best bet would be to enforce this through a trigger, although triggers on MySQL unfortunately are not always as easy as they ought to be.

Comment: And, of course, if you want proper "foreign key" like behaviour, you have to write triggers for each remote table as well (to either prevent or cascade deletes and updates)